# MUIのYearPickerのSelectedカラーを変更する方法はありますか？

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

muiのDatePicker APIを使用しています。
年度選択時のバックグラウンドカラーを変更したいのですが、方法が見つかりません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

日付選択はPickersDayコンポーネントのsxにstyleを指定して、それをDatePickerのrenderDayに渡せば変更できました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

方法をご存知の方、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

YearPickerのButtonの色は以下のクラスでスタイリングされていることが、Dev toolでみてみるとわかると思います。
単純に、このクラスに対するCSSを上書きしてしまうのはどうでしょうか？

```css
.css-3eghsz-PrivatePickersYear-button.Mui-selected {
　　color: #fff;
 background-color: #1976d2;
}
```

Codesandboxで試してみた際のLink:
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-leftpad-5y9id1?file=/public/style.css

上記のSandboxは以下のリンクのデモコードをフォークして編集しました。
https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/#react-components